# No response when click on approve button

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a project which is document managment system in this itry to apporve/reject documents and fr this 
i create sp for approve and reject document

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sprejectapprove]
        @UserID int,
        @DocID int,
        @ApproveType nvarchar(50)
as
    Insert into Approval(UserID,DocID,ApproveType)
    values(@UserID,@DocID,@ApproveType)
```

approve:

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[spinsertapprove]
     @UserID int,
     @DocID int,
     @ApproveType nvarchar(50)
 as
     Insert into Approval(UserID,DocID,ApproveType)
     values(@UserID,@DocID,@ApproveType)
```

and code is

```
protected void GrdFileApprove_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "_Approve")
    {
        //using (SqlConnection con = DataAccess.GetConnected())
        using (SqlConnection con = 
                 new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)     

            ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                LinkButton Prove_Button =   
               (LinkButton)row.FindControl("BtnApprove");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spinsertapprove", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
                }
            }

            catch 
            {
                apfi.Text = "Not Approve";
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    else if (e.CommandName == "_Reject")
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = 
                    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)
                ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                LinkButton Prove_Button = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("Button1");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sprejectapprove", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
                }
            }

            catch 
            {
                apfi.Text = "Rejct";
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i debug the code and click on approve or reject button it can not further proceed and also not show me any error

this is grdiview

```
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
         <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPanle" 
            ondatabinding="UPanle_DataBinding_Click">
            <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="GrdFileApprove" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                onrowcommand="GrdFileApprove_RowCommand" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GrdFileApprove_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S no">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                           <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HdnFileID" Value='<%#
                       Eval("DocID") %>' />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="DocID" HeaderText="DocumentID"  />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="DocName" HeaderText="DocName"  />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Uploadfile" HeaderText="File Name" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="DocType" HeaderText="Document" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="DepType" HeaderText="Department" />
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S no">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Button runat="server" Id="BtnApprove" 
                        CommandName="_Approve" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocID") %>' 
                            Text="Aprrove"   />
                           <asp:Button runat="server" Id="Button1"
                           CommandName="_Reject" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocID") %>' Text="Reject" />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
       </ContentTemplate>


        </asp:UpdatePanel> 

</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the ASPX markup where your GridView is declared?

Comment: are you able to run in debug mode? if you set a breakpoint in the RowCommand handler is it hit? what is the value of e.CommandName ?

Comment: yes i set a breakpoint but when i debug and press f11 then it still cant proceeddd

Comment: Why do you need two stored procedures when they do the same thing apart from putting different `ApproveType` values into the database?

Comment: in database ther3 is 3 approved types  1 approved 2 reject 3 pending when click on approve button the values userid docid and approve type goes to approve table..and there is separate approve and approve type table

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding any parameter values to your SQL calls so the stored procedures are probably not being called at all as you haven't got any default values on the definitions.

You need to add the following for each parameter before the calls:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userId);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocID", docId);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApproveType", "Approve");
```

with the last one being:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApproveType", "Reject");
```

for the reject case.

The values need to be read from where ever they are stored rather than being hard coded of course.

Comment: it still not give me any responce when i click approve or reject button

Comment: @user2832406 - Check in the debugger that the right values are being passed into the parameters. Modify the stored procedure so that it does something else so you can verify that it's actually getting called. Use SQL Trace to verify that the stored procedure is getting called.